# Shifting to spritesheets causes flicker in spite of extruding

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I have a cocos2d iOS game that was originally built with direct images (without spritesheets). I am migrating to spritesheets, and used Texture Packer to generate the spritesheets. I have several elements that are rendered next to each other, which worked fine in the initial non-spritesheet mode. Once I put those images in spritesheets, there is some flicker at the boundaries of the images. I have used extrude of 2 pixels with each spritesheet, and some of the flicker is eliminated, but there are still a couple. I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible that the flicker is due to ImageOptim being run on the images? I don't think this is the problem, since I remember that even with optimized images, the flicker didn't occur.
2. Some of the images that adjoin each other are in different spritesheets due to different RGB settings - could this cause the problem? I could put the adjoining images into the same spritesheet, but that would cause a bit of overhead in terms of memory, since I may be putting, for example, an opaque image along with a translucent image with RGBA4444 (instead of RGB565 for opaque).
3. I am assuming that the rendering logic doesn't need to be changed. Is it possible that rendering the images to overlap (as suggested by some responses to eliminate flicker) might fix the issue?

Comment: what is ImagOptim? A TP featureor a tool? 2. maybe, just try it. It's quick to do with TP.

Comment: http://imageoptim.com/ - a tool that efficiently compresses images. Will try 2 and post an update

Comment: Forget that. First, if you have Optimize PNG enabled in Build Settings any "optimizations" made by the tool are null and void. Second if you care enough to "optimize" image files, use the best image file format available: .pvr.ccz - smallest files, least memory usage, and very fast loading. Even when compared to PNG.

Comment: I don't have optimise png enabled in build settings. Also, I run imageoptim on pngs before putting them in sprite sheets - the sprite sheets are pvr.ccz. Are you suggesting that the individual images that go into sprite sheets also be converted to pvr.ccz first?

Comment: I tried option 2. It did fix the problem, but now, only on iPad first gen (i.e, NOT in iphone 3gs, iphone 4, ipad 3rd gen - don't have other devices to test), I get a low memory warning. BTW, I am preloading all assets, and it works fine on all devices except ipad first gen. Will try to optimize further to avoid ipad low memory and let you know how it goes.